# Fail to push_back() derived class into STL list in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, abstract-class

I would appreciate any help with this.

The problem is that I can not successfully push_back something into a STL list.
Here are details:

`Fo` is a abstract class and `Foo` is a class inherit from `Fo`.
`f0`, `f1` are instances of the class `Foo`.
`fooList` has type `std::list<Foo>` and `foList` has type `std::list<Fo*>`.

When I try `fooList.push_back(f1);` I can `cout` the value for member `p`, but can not call function `test()`;
When I try `foList.push_back(&f1);` I even can not `cout` the value for member p, let alone call function `test()`.

With lines with error-1/2/3 commented, I obtained the output:

```
Fo constructor
Foo constructor
Fo constructor
Foo initialization 
Fo constructor
Foo copy constructor
inside fooList :11
------------------------
```

I also realize `foList.push_back(&f1)` did not call `Foo` copy constructor,
which may be relevant for error-2.

When I try to call function `test()` in `fooList`, I obtain an error msg:

```
error: member function 'test' not viable: 'this' argument has type
  'const Foo', but function is not marked const
```

When I try to cout member p in `foList`, I obtain an error msg:

```
error: no member named 'p' in 'Fo'
```

I have no idea how to fix the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Full code list below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Fo
{
public:
    Fo() { std::cout << "Fo constructor" << std::endl; }
    Fo(const Fo& f) { std::cout << "Fo copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Fo(){};
    virtual void test()=0;
};

class Foo : public Fo
{
public:
    int p;
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl; }
    Foo(int p_): p(p_) {std::cout << "Foo initialization " << std::endl;};
    Foo(const Foo& f) { this->p = f.p; std::cout << "Foo copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    virtual void test() {std::cout<<"testing Foo ... "<<std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    Foo f0,f1(11);

    std::list<Foo> fooList;
    std::list<Foo>::const_iterator i=fooList.begin();
    fooList.push_back(f1);i++;
    std::cout << "inside fooList :" << i->p << std::endl;
    //std::cout<<"inside fooList :"<<i->p<<" and "<<i->test();  // error-1
    std::cout << "------------------------" << std::endl;

    std::list<Fo*> foList;
    std::list<Fo*>::const_iterator it=foList.begin();
    foList.push_back(&f1);it++;
    //std::cout<<(*it)->p<<std::endl;  // error-2
    //std::cout<<"inside foList :"<<(*it)->p<<" and "<<it->test();  // error-3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is that if you're doing derivation, you need to store pointers, not the objects. A container of base objects can only hold base objects, not derived objects. If you fix things so the code compiles, the best you can hope for is "slicing", which means instances of the derived object are actually converted to base class objects, and those converted base class objects are what get stored in your list.

Comment: Doesn't work, since the objects are copied and the container really only stores objects of the declared type. BTW: If you want to "prove" anything using that output in constructor and destructor, you are missing a few, check out the so-called "Law of Three".

Comment: I wonder what's unclear about these error messages. They say exactly where the problems are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix

```
//std::cout<<"inside fooList :"<<i->p<<" and "<<i->test();  // error-1
```

change

```
std::list<Foo>::const_iterator i=fooList.begin();
```

to

```
std::list<Foo>::iterator i=fooList.begin();
```

To fix

```
//std::cout<<(*it)->p<<std::endl;  // error-2
```

replace with

```
std::cout<<(Foo*(*it))->p<<std::endl;  // error-2
```

To fix:

```
//std::cout<<"inside foList :"<<(*it)->p<<" and "<<it->test();  // error-3
```

replace

```
//std::cout<<"inside foList :"<<(Foo*(*it))->p<<" and "<<it->test();  // error-3
```

Comment: I got your point for error-2. I need a type conversions. But following the way you did compiler still show error msg for error-1.

Comment: some more errors at your's code, change return type of test() from void to int in both place, chande const_iterator to iterator in both place, and change it->test() to (*it)->test() at error-3

Comment: It works now. And it seems there is no need to replace const_iterator with iterator.  Could you tell me why the return type matters here? Thank you.

Comment: This is the theme for separate question/

Comment: Shortly say '<<' - is the overloaded function operator<<(Type param) and There is no scpecial overloaded implementation for void type. So change void to int or any valid type.